# How do I add a control to allow the user to change the accuracy setting for the IOS Location sensor?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to add a switch in my iOS app to let the user control the accuracy of the location by using kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and kCLLocationAccuracyReduced. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.